# I don't really understand what a model is.

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

I've studied a bit of first order logic, and I still don't understand what a model **really** is.

> A model of a theory $T$ is an interpretation which assigns the value True to its sentences.

Ok, that's pretty clear, I guess.

But then I run into things like this:

Let $T$ be the axioms of the ordered fields, then $(\Bbb R,+,\cdot)$ is a model of $T$.

At a glance, this looks OK, I mean, $\Bbb R$ satisfies all the axioms. But why?

Well, if we take the standard construction of $\Bbb R$ as dedekind cuts, we can see that $\Bbb R$ does satisfy them, **IF** $\Bbb Q$ does.

So we have to go back to the construction of, $\Bbb Q$, and realize we've defined this as $\Bbb Q = (\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z)/\equiv_1$ for a suitable equivalence relation $\equiv_1$, then again, $\Bbb Q$ satisfies the axioms if $\Bbb Z$ some others...

Finally we're back to how we define $\Bbb N$, we don't really have a step below this (like we had with $\Bbb R,\Bbb Q, \Bbb Z$), so we assume some stuff (like the Peano axioms)?

---

I believe this is a problem: by the completeness/soundness theorem of FOL, we have that $T$ defined as before must be consistent, as it has a model.  However, isn't the consistence of $T$ dependend on the consistence of (in this case) Peano axioms?

Wouldn't we require a model of P.A?

I'm not sure I've made clear my confusions, as all of this is still pretty fuzzy in my head, if anything needs clarification, please leave a comment.

Comment: Is this not exactly what the axiom of infinity is meant to do, in set theory? It ensures there is an infinite object which we can treat as $\mathbb{N}$. (I'm not completely satisfied with my understanding either.)

Comment: Sure, at some point one needs the observation that the natural numbers satisfy the Peano axioms.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Are you aware that you can define $\mathbb N$, the successor function, etc and then prove this entity satisfies the PA?

Comment: @GitGud The thing is, how do you define it? Via ZF? If that's the case, isn't then the problem just translated from the consistency of PA (finding a model) to finding a model of ZF?

Comment: Your question doesn't actually seem to be "what is a model?" is it "how do we prove that a given structure is a model of $T$ without some foundational assumptions?" Am I correct?

Comment: @James Yes, I believe you've summed up my question in a better way.

Comment: I think I am of the opinion that doubting that PA is consistent at the same level of doubting whether there is an infinite set, in either case, the question isn't really mathematical.

Comment: The existence of the integers is clear, and using them and *informal set theory*, we construct the reals.  The purpose of model theory is not foundational, it is to provide useful additional ideas for the analysis of ordinary mathematical structures. Like group theory, or numerical analysis.

Comment: A *model* is a "piece of world" satisfying the axioms (and the theorems) of the theory. In most cases, the "piece of world" is a *mathematical structure*, like *natural* numbers for the theory of arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tarski analysed what it means to give a semantics to a formal language. One of his conclusions is that we need to separate the concept of the "object language" (the language whose semantics we want to define) from the concept of the "metalanguage" (the language we are going to use to formulate the definition of the semantics).

For the vast majority of mathematical logicians, the metalanguage is just the usual semiformal mixture of words and symbols that most mathematical discourse involves. For them a model of PA would be given by the natural numbers of everyday mathematical practice.

You could take a much more formal view and take something like ZF set theory as your metalanguage, but that would involve a great deal of unnecessary work for someone who is just interested in using formal logic to investigate mathematical structures or studying it for its own intrinsic intellectual interest. If you took this approach, a model of PA would be given by something like von Neumann's construction of the natural numbers in ZF.

Whichever approach you take, you get no guarantees of consistency, but that isn't really the object of the exercise. If you actually want to construct models for an object language, then you need to make some ontological assumptions in your metalanguage. However, to work with object language syntax, you need to reason about strings of symbols and that is not really different from reasoning about natural numbers. So if you reject PA (or some constructive approximation to it), you have already rejected mathematical logic.

See this [SEP article about Tarski's ideas](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/) for more discussion and references.

Comment: That's the problem: Each time you go for a 'better' metalanguage, like $\sf ZF$, (provided you have some sort of soundness theorem) you  end up requiring a "metametalanguage" to allow you to construct a model of your metalanguage, if you want to guarantee somehow the consistency, right?

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't see this as a problem. A mathematical proof of the consistency of mathematics is not a goal of modern mathematical logic.

Comment: I have expanded the answer to say a bit more about ontological (foundational) assumptions.

Comment: Well, if Tarski said that, _Tarski said that_.